# Staccato and legato on a violin simultaneously?

Tags: violin, legato, staccato

Can anybody explain to me how it is possible, if possible at all, to play staccato and legato on a violin simultaneously?
Here is a score I stumbled upon on YouTube:

As far as I know, the dot above a note means that the player is supposed to play that note very shortly (staccato), while a curve above two or more than two notes means that the notes are to be played in a "mingled way", that is, smoothly transitioning from one to another.

But in the above-mentioned score I see these two opposite things denoted as to be performed at the same time!:

[image]

How is that physically possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In violin music the slur means means the bow direction does not change. Normally this results in *legato*. In your example the bow stops and restarts for each pair of notes, and the next pair of notes would be played with the bow moving in the opposite direction.

Comment: Thank you. You said, "In violin music the slur means the bow direction does not change" - So, that means that those notes in my example are all played in staccato and none of them are played in legato then. Am I correct?

Comment: No it’s not staccato, it means notes are ‘detached’ rather than legato but with the bow moving in one direction per slur. The linked duplicate question has more info.